# SKProductsResponse only returns invalid product ID's

Tags: ios

I'm trying to wire up IAP. The app is on Test Flight. The bundle ID and appID are correct.

```
    func requestProductData(productIdentifier: String) {

    let pIDS = Set([productIdentifier])

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: pIDS)
        request.delegate = self
        print("yes") // make sure we can pay
        request.start()
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In App Purchase in Settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
            if url != nil {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
            }

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.viewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

    print("these are the response products: \(response.products)")
    print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    print("received response")

}
```

I'm passing in the Product ID copied directly off of iTunes. The entitlements are correct. `SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()` comes back true, however it doesn't ask for my sandbox ID even though I've logged out of the store on the testing device.

I've been testing on a device and on simulator with the same results. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Currently this is what the In-App purchase looks like in iTunes. I can submit a new version for review however that doesn't seem to be correct as this application is not in the app store yet, only in Test Flight.

> Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version.
>   Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.

^That whole instruction block is thoroughly confusing. While reading that I'm already in the In-App Purchase section and there is no submit button. I've uploaded a new version and still no submit button.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did not have bank account information filled out in the contracts section of iTunes Connect. You must have contracts filled out and processed for any products to return.